# Is there any callback function for Upload Image addon for CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I am using CKeditor in my project and I have a requirement where I need to upload images too.

I have downloaded http://ckeditor.com/addon/uploadimage Addon and it works fine. It perfectly sends data to server too.

I just needed to add

```
CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/browser/browse.php';
CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/uploader/upload.php';
```

to make it work.

But issue is, I want to to send additional parameters to server as well, so I know which product/item is being edited.

Sending just image to server makes no sense to me, CKEditor has no information on it. Can someone please help me to send additional parameter to `UploadUrl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set `CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserUploadUrl` dynamically when you call `CKEDITOR.replace()`; this gives the ability to set different `UploadUrl` in different page.

In your case I think you just need append different query string to `uploadUrl`

like:

```
CKEDITOR.replace(
    textarea_name,  
    {filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '/uploader/upload.php?productId=123', 
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/uploader/upload.php'}
)
```

In serverside upload.php you can receive `productId` when upload process is done, pass the `productId` to a callback function;

Comment: ah crap I am so stupid ... how on earth I didnt think of adding that product id in query string ... i wish i could vote you 10 times ... thanks